# SingnalR with Redis Send Msg to Specific ConnectionID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redis, signalr, signalr-hub, backbone.signalr

> I am using SingalR for my Chat Application. Wanted to play with Redis
>   and SignalR but **I cannot find an working example where i can send msg to
>   specific connectionId**. Below Code that works for a single server instance.
>   But when i make it a Web Garden with 3 process it stops working as my
>   server instance that gets the message cannot find the connectionId
>   for that destination UserId to send the message.

```
private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = new ConnectionMapping<string>();
        public void Send(string sendTo, string message, string from)
        {
            string fromclientid = Context.QueryString["clientid"];

            foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(sendTo))
            {
                Clients.Client(connectionId).send(fromclientid, message);

            }

            Clients.Caller.send(sendTo, "me: " + message);

        }

            public override Task OnConnected()
            {
            int clientid = Convert.ToInt32(Context.QueryString["clientid"]);

            _connections.Add(clientid.ToString(), Context.ConnectionId);

            }
```

> I have used the example below to setup my box and code **but none of
>   them have examples for sending from one client to specific client or
>   group of specific clients.**

```
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-redis
https://github.com/mickdelaney/SignalR.Redis/tree/master/Redis.Sample
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ConnectionMapping instance in your Hub class will not synced across different SignalR server instances. You need to use permanent external storage such as a database or a Windows Azure table. Refer to this link for more details:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/mapping-users-to-connections